# htaccess Mod Rewrite home.php to be removed

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an index.php page which has a redirect on to go to home.php

is there anyway using htaccess i can make home.php be hidden so the user just see's the domain name in the address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure you can use this rewrite rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: is someone accesses domain.com/index.php can i make the index.php dissapear? i have taken off home.php and replaced it with index.php so i am using RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [L]

Comment: ok check updated code now. Now if user visits `http://domain.con/index.php` it will be redirected to `http://domain.con/` and silently `/index.php` content will be shown.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any problems with this.